# Date from string is not working in iOS

Tags: ios, nsdate, nsdateformatter

I am using following code.  Every time I get a null value for date.

```
NSString *dateStr = @"06/10/2013";
NSDateFormatter *dateFormat = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[dateFormat setDateFormat:@"MMM dd, YYYY"];
NSDate *date = [dateFormat dateFromString:dateStr];
NSLog(@"date %@",date);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are passing the wrong format. `NSDateFormatter` uses [date format patterns from UNICODE](http://unicode.org/reports/tr35/tr35-6.html#Date_Format_Patterns). So correct the format and will work fine. Here you can try this:

```
NSString *dateStr = @"06/10/2013";
NSDateFormatter *dateFormat = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[dateFormat setDateFormat:@"MM/dd/YYYY"];
NSDate *date = [dateFormat dateFromString:dateStr];
NSLog(@"date %@",date);
```

Also,do have a better look at [Apple's Date Formatting guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/DataFormatting/DataFormatting.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/10000029i) too .

**EDIT:**
I found from some of your comments that what you are trying to do is to change the format, but your question didn't mean that. If you are trying to change the format, you need to convert it back to NSString after setting dateformatter format to required one. Add this to the bottom and check:

```
[dateFormat setDateFormat:@"MMM, dd,yyyy"];
NSString *dateStrinfFormated = [dateFormat stringFromDate:date];
NSLog(@"Date in required format: %@",dateStrinfFormated);
```

Comment: Does `setDateFormat` have to use that exact format?  ie do you have to use `/` as a separator?

Comment: Separator is also included in the format! exact format is requited, separators like " ", /, - ... should be considered seriously

Comment: it took me an hour to figure out why my date formatter wasn't working and it was because YYYY is incorrect. use yyyy

Answer (score 2):

Get some valid `date format` from your `NSString`, then convert it again, to get the output how you want,

```
NSString *dateStr = @"06/10/2013";
NSDateFormatter *dateFormat = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[dateFormat setDateFormat:@"MM/dd/yyyy"];
NSDate *validDate = [dateFormat dateFromString:dateStr];
NSLog(@"Valid Date %@",validDate);             // 2013-06-09 18:30:00 +0000
[dateFormat setDateFormat:@"MMM, dd,yyyy"];
NSString *str = [dateFormat stringFromDate:validDate];
NSLog(@"Result String %@",str);               // Jun, 10,2013
```

Answer (score 0):

```
[dateFormat setDateFormat:@"MM/dd/yyyy"];
```

Comment: i want date in "Jun 12, 2013" format. i am not able to find the exact date format.

Comment: @KAT You can't change the format of NSDate object! If you need to change the format, you should convert the date back to NSString with required format

Comment: DD is day of year (1..365), YYYY is year in "Week of Year"-based calendars. @"MM/dd/yyyy" is more correct. A better approach is to use something like NSDateFormatterMediumStyle to get "Jun 12, 2013" or appropriate equivalent for the locale.